# Using htaccess to internally and externally redirect a page at the same time

Tags: htaccess, redirects, trailing-slash, file-extension

I've been trying to figure this out for two hours, and I give up. I want to externally redirect about.php to about/, and also have about/ internally redirect to about.php

```
RewriteRule ^about/$ /test/about.php [L]    
RewriteRule ^about\.php$ /test/about/ [R,L]
```

Both of these rules work fine by themselves, but when they're combined they cause an endless loop (since each rule undoes the other one).

How can I combine them without causing an endless loop?

EDIT: In the "related" tab it shows a question that's exactly the same as this that I just couldn't seem to find myself through Google, and the solution works perfectly:

[Using a .htaccess to RewriteRule and Redirect 301 at the same time?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67479/using-a-htaccess-to-rewriterule-and-redirect-301-at-the-same-time?rq=1)

This:

```
RewriteRule ^about/$ /test/about.php [L,E=CLEAN_CONTACT_URL:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_CLEAN_CONTACT_URL} !1
RewriteRule ^about\.php$ /test/about/ [R=301,L]
```

works exactly the way that I wanted, I just didn't know how to use RewriteCond to do something like this. Now I'm glad I posted my question!

Comment: Yes you would get a loop. When you say internally, do you mean internal IP addresses?

Comment: I guess it would be good to know the range too. Can you provide the IP address range you are intending if it applies?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the right term for it - by "internally" I meant redirecting without changing the URL in the address bar (like, about/ shows the content of about.php)

and this is just in general, I want mydomain.com/about.php to change to mydomain.com/about/ in the address bar, but still have mydomain.com/about/ show the content of about.php

Comment: Do you mean this for different sets of user?

Comment: You cannot do both without distinguishing a case for when this should happen. Often this is for internal company IP addresses. But it could be on a directory by directory basis. Do you have a directory list where you want exceptions?

Comment: I just realized that if I change the filename to something else, like about_content.php, that fixes the infinite loop problem, but I would still like to know the answer anyway.

Comment: You are right about changing the file name. There is no way to convert about.php to /about/ and then back again without a condition of some sort. You will end up with a loop.

Comment: BTW- every time there is a match in the .htaccess file and a change is made to the URL/URI, .htaccess is entered again from the top to ensure that there are no other rules that apply. There has to be an out of some kind to avoid some conditions. FYI.

Comment: Yes, I just didn't know how to write a condition that would stop it from happening, but I found the answer on another question. How do you mark a question as a duplicate?

Comment: You can use the *flag* link below your question. If you cannot, put the link into a comment and I can do it for you. Not sure if you can do this as a new user. There is one way to find out of course- try it!

Comment: Thanks - you have to have "reputation" to do that and I don't have any so that option doesn't show up LOL I edited my original question to add the link to the one it duplicates.

Comment: Done. I had to step out and shovel some snow. That's the life of a landlord!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^about/$ /test/about.php [L]    
RewriteRule ^about\.php$ /test/about/ [R,L]
```

This is probably just your example, but this shouldn't actually result in a rewrite loop because of the additional `/test` subdirectory in the substitution. (`/test/about.php` won't match the pattern `^about\.php$`)

But anyway, assuming you want to (internally) rewrite `/about/` to `/about.php` and (externally) redirect `/about.php` back to `/about/` (user friendly URL), then your solution can be optimised. There is no need to set an environment variable. (Note also, that you only need to do the external redirection if you are changing an existing URL structure. If this is a new site and the "unfriendly" URLs have not been indexed or exposed, then the external redirection is not necessary.)

Generally, external redirections should come before any internal rewrites. The rewrite loop can be avoided by checking against `%{THE_REQUEST}`, which contains the initial HTTP request. (so, no need for the environment variable to remember state.) So this can be rewritten as:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /about\.php
RewriteRule ^about\.php$ /about/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^about/$ /about.php [L]
```

As mentioned, `%{THE_REQUEST}` contains the initial HTTP request (which does not change), which is of the form: `GET /about.php HTTP/1.1`

It's also good practise to separate rule sets with a blank line once you start using `RewriteCond` directives to make it clear (more readable) that the `RewriteCond` directive only applies to the single `RewriteRule` directive that follows.

Checking for `about.php` in the `RewriteRule` (as well as `RewriteCond`) might seem unnecessary at first, since the `RewriteCond` directive is what actually prevents the rewrite loop, but this is actually required for efficiency. Since the `RewriteRule` is tested first, this ensures that only relevant requests are processed.